# Search query IQueryable<> MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, iqueryable

I Have a problem with my search query that it doesnt select any values from the database when i iam using IQueryable<> in MVC.

My code look like this:

```
IQueryable<Invoice> res =
            (from c in table
                join i in tableX on c.attr equals i.Id
                where c.attr== merchant
                select i);


        if (buyer > 0)
        {
            res = res.Where(i => i.Buyer.Msisdn == buyer);
        }

        if (send)
        {
            res =res.Where(i => i.Status == InvoiceStatus.Sent);                 
        }
        if (paid)
        {
            res=  res.Where(i => i.Status == InvoiceStatus.Paid);
        }
        if (notBilled)
        {
            res = res.Where(i => i.Status == InvoiceStatus.Open);
        }

        if (startDate <= endDate)
        {
            res =  res.Where(i => i.DateCreated >= startDate && i.DateCreated <= endDate);
        }

        return res.ToList();
```

if i dont set res = res.Where() and instead just have res.where() the query is selecting the values from the database. Can someone please make me understand why that is. I thought you need to store the query result in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've posted looks to be the appropriate way to implement IQueryable.

```
res = res.Where(...)
```

basically tacks on additional where clause information until the query is executed at `res.ToList();`.

calling `res.Where` doesn't actually make changes to the `res` query.

You're likely just limiting your where clause too much and eliminating all records from the query.

Have you tried profiling the query to determine what is being queried?

I can tell you that if more than one of `send`, `paid`, or `notbilled` is true, that would immediately not allow any results to be returned from the query as they're all checking against the `Status` column - which could not possibly have more than one value.

EDIT

I don't know if this will help, but here's a fiddle going through some of the intricacies of IQueryable: https://dotnetfiddle.net/d70XKA

Here's the code from the fiddle:

```
public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        Thingy t = new Thingy();

        // Note execution is deferred until enumeration (in this case Count())
        var allData = t.GetData();
        Console.WriteLine("All Data count: {0}", allData.Count());

        // Select only valid records from data set (should be 2)
        var isValid = t.GetData();
        isValid = isValid.Where(w => w.IsValid);
        Console.WriteLine("IsValid count: {0}", isValid.Count());

        // select only records with an ID greater than 1 (should be 2)
        var gt1 = t.GetData();
        gt1 = gt1.Where(w => w.Id > 1);
        Console.WriteLine("gt 1 count: {0}", gt1.Count());

        // Here we're combining in a single statement, IsValid and gt 1 (should be 1)
        var isValidAndIdGt1 = t.GetData();
        isValidAndIdGt1 = isValidAndIdGt1.Where(w => w.IsValid && w.Id > 1);
        Console.WriteLine("IsValid and gt 1 count: {0}", isValidAndIdGt1.Count());

        // This is the same query as the one directly above, just broken up (could perhaps be some if logic in there to determine if to add the second Where
        // Note this is how you're doing it in your question (and it's perfectly valid (should be 1)
        var isValidAndIdGt1Appended = t.GetData();
        isValidAndIdGt1Appended = isValidAndIdGt1Appended.Where(w => w.IsValid);
        isValidAndIdGt1Appended = isValidAndIdGt1Appended.Where(w => w.Id > 1);
        Console.WriteLine("IsValid and gt 1 count w/ appended where: {0}", isValidAndIdGt1Appended.Count());

        // This is the same query as the one directly above, but note we are executing the query twice
        var isValidAndIdGt1AppendedTwice = t.GetData();
        isValidAndIdGt1AppendedTwice = isValidAndIdGt1AppendedTwice.Where(w => w.IsValid);
        Console.WriteLine("IsValid and gt 1 count w/ appended where executing twice: {0}", isValidAndIdGt1AppendedTwice.Count()); // 2 results are valid
        isValidAndIdGt1AppendedTwice = isValidAndIdGt1AppendedTwice.Where(w => w.Id > 1);
        Console.WriteLine("IsValid and gt 1 count w/ appended where executing twice: {0}", isValidAndIdGt1AppendedTwice.Count()); // 1 result is both valid and id gt 1

        // This is one of the things you were asking about - note that without assigning the additional Where criteria to the Iqueryable, you do not get the results of the where clause, but the original query - in this case there are no appended where conditions on the t.GetData() call, so you get the full result set.
        var notReallyValid = t.GetData();
        notReallyValid.Where(w => w.Name == "this name definitly does not exist");
        Console.WriteLine("where clause not correctly appended count: {0}", notReallyValid.Count());

        // vs
        var validUse = t.GetData();
        validUse = validUse.Where(w => w.Name == "this name definitly does not exist");
        Console.WriteLine("valid use count: {0}", validUse.Count());

    }

}

public class Thingy
{
    private List<Foo> _testData = new List<Foo>()
    {
        new Foo()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Alpha",
            Created = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1),
            IsValid = true
        },
        new Foo()
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Beta",
            Created = new DateTime(2015, 2, 1),
            IsValid = false
        },
        new Foo()
        {
            Id = 3,
            Name = "Gamma",
            Created = new DateTime(2015, 3, 1),
            IsValid = true
        },          
    };

    public IQueryable<Foo> GetData()
    {
        return _testData.AsQueryable();
    }

    public void PrintData(IEnumerable<Foo> data)
    {
        // Note calling this will enumerate the data for IQueryable
        foreach (Foo f in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("id: {0}, name: {1}, created: {2}, isValid: {3}", f.Id, f.Name, f.Created, f.IsValid));
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}
```

Having said all of that, there is something in your where clause that is filtering out your expected data.  As you can see from the example above `res = res.Where(...)` is very different from `res.Where(...)` - the former is the correct approach.  The latter is simply omitting all where clauses from your statement completely, then when `ToList()` is called you're getting the full result set as no `Where` conditions have been added (save `where c.attr== merchant` from the original var creation)

Comment: Send, paid and notBilled are checkboxes in the GUI so if thats true thats gets in the query. But i get your point. that if the user checks all boxes they point all at the same status

Comment: Okey thanks for the help and very good information. I think i solved it now. It was a problem with the query and res = res.Where() actually works.

Answer (score 0):

IQueryable objects don't actually contain data until you either do a ToList().  Until then they're just queries.  So what you've done in you assignment is replaced the query with ... I don't know what.  What you should do is something like this:

```
IQueryable Results = res.Where(i => i.Status == InvoiceStatus.Paid); //(or whatever)
return (Results.ToList());
```

Comment: Yes this was my first thougt to have another Iqueryable Results and append each where clause to that. But that doesn't work so i dont know.